# Can't write with pandas to_parquet() into ADLS Gen 2

Tags: pandas, pyspark, azure-databricks

I used the following code snippet in a Databricks notebook to write parquet files on ADLS Gen2 for the past couple of months (obviously some parts of the path changed).

```
df.toPandas().to_parquet('abfss://landing@[REDACTED].dfs.core.windows.net/corporate/ax/TABLENAME/2022/07/TABLENAME_20220728.parquet', storage_options={'account_name': '[REDACTED]', 'account_key': '[REDACTED]'})
```

Today the pipeline failed with the following error `Failed to upload block. The specified resource name contains invalid characters.` The thing is that nothing changed, the storage account name is the same, and the container is also the same. I'm really struggling for ideas here, as I tried multiple different things but with no effect (switching path syntax from `container@storage\file-path` to just `container\file-path`, using connection-string option instead of access key ones, etc.).

Could you please suggest anything?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

> Error: Failed to upload block. The specified resource name contains
> invalid characters.

**Cause of Error:**

When there are characters introduced to the Container Name which do not follow the Azure storage.

Follow the rules below to get rid of this error.

1. Container name should be in lower case and it must be from 3 to 69 characters long.
2. Container names must start or end with a letter or number, and can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character.
3. Every dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container names.
4. Try to copy path as it is from azure environment to avoid any typing errors.

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata#container-names

Comment: The container's called 'landing', I believe it does follow the naming rules. Same with the storage account name. On top of that, the names did not change since 2021 and they were fine, so I don't think that's the actual problem here.